# Displaying a different message every 10 seconds for a loading page

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-animate

I am wanting to create a loading page that would display a message every 10 seconds much like the one on the Mibbit Web Chat loading page. I would either like the messages to fade out and then a new one show or it could also slide the current message to the left and the new message slides from the right. I am sure this is not as difficult as I think it is, but I am unable to find an answer anywhere.

I am perfectly fine with using Javascript or jQuery on this as I am certain those are the only ways.

I appreciate any help in advance.

Comment: I have tried nothing as I can not find a tutorial or anything explaining how to do what I am wanting.

Comment: @Scott Did you try searching for "display a message every 10 seconds in javascript"? It worked for me.

Comment: Ok, to get started read up on setInterval in Javascript and fadeIn and fadeOut in jQuery. Pretty straight forward from there...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To fire a function every 10 seconds, use [`setInterval`](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_win_setinterval.asp). Then, you just need to play around with [`.fadeIn()`](http://api.jquery.com/fadeIn/), [`.fadeOut()`](http://api.jquery.com/fadeOut/), or any other [effect](http://api.jquery.com/category/effects/):

```
var i = 1;
var sampleMessages = [ "First message", "Second message", "Third, now repeat" ];
setInterval(function() {
  var newText = sampleMessages[i++ % sampleMessages.length];
  $("#message").fadeOut(500, function () {
    $(this).text(newText).fadeIn(500);
  });
}, 10 * 1000);​ // Interval is in milliseconds
```

Here's a **[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/nrnJu/)**.

Comment: Thanks for your help, I am starting to understand the setInterval() command now. I needed to see it in action to grasp it, that's just how I learn.

Answer (score 0):

I won't write the code for you. But here's something to put you in the right direction.

## [setInterval()](http://www.w3schools.com/js/js_timing.asp)

> The setInterval() method will wait a specified number of milliseconds,
>   and then execute a specified function, and it will continue to execute
>   the function, once at every given time-interval.

## [.fadeToggle()](http://api.jquery.com/fadeToggle/)

> The .fadeToggle() method animates the opacity of the matched elements.
>   When called on a visible element, the element's display style property
>   is set to none once the opacity reaches 0, so the element no longer
>   affects the layout of the page.

Using a combination of these functions with an array

## [Math.random()](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_random.asp)

> The random() method returns a random number between 0 and 1.

Using a combination of these methods combined with an array of random phrases you should be able to achieve the result you are looking for.